# Cross correlate a 2D array

Tags: convolution, python, cross-correlation, correlation, eeg

I have a 2D array of eeg data with shape (64,512) - 64 electrodes, 512 timepoints

I want to calculate the maximum cross correlation (irrespective of lag/time shift) between every single electrode, so I end up with a 64x64 array containing max cross correlation values between all pairs

Is there an efficient way of doing this in python/numpy/scipy without iterating through all pairs of electrodes?

I tried using `scipy.signal.correlate2d` but I'm not sure its doing what I think its doing as I end up with a 2D array of size 127x1023 rather than 64x64:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(1,100,(64,512))

xcorr = signal.correlate2d(data,data)
```

Comment: For those looking for 'actual' 2D, see [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/85962/50076+)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have (conceptually) is not a 2D array but a collection of 1D arrays. `correlate2D` is designed to perform a 2D correlation calculation, so that's not what you need.
Iterating through all pairs is not a big ask really - you can still use `numpy` to perform the cross correlation, you'll just need to have two loops (nested) to determine which signals to perform the calculation on. With only 64 signals that shouldn't take long.

`for first in range(n_signals):
    for second in range(first + 1, n_signals):
        corr = numpy.correlate(data[first], data[second], mode='full')
        max_corr[first, second] = numpy.max(corr)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.corr() # Compute pairwise correlation of columns, excluding NA/null values.
```

you can see that in pandas documentation
it means you do not need the loop
plus you can choose the method of cor

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE!  Providing code that, in addition to the OP's code, will run immediately is more useful than just a single line. Also, please format code using the code format button (as I've edited it to do).

Answer (score 0):

You can focus on the scipy.signal.correlate() function instead of scipy.signal.correlate2d()
[scipy.signal.correlate()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).