# FFT2D on a vector 1D

Tags: fft, cross-correlation

My question is related to [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/85917/cross-correlation-of-2d-fft-using-1d-fft)

I have a 1D vector, the target vector, represented as 2D (knowing the nr of cols and rows) to which i need to apply an FFT2D.
Having only the FFT1D, in order to obtain a FFT2D, i will need to apply it on each row and then on each column.

```
std::vector<double> targetVector;
int nrColTargetVector = 18, nrRowTargetVector = 17, fft2Cols, fft2Rows;
std::vector<complex> fft1DTargetVectorRows;
std::vector<complex> fft2DTargetVector;
auto newFFT = new FFT;
int flag = 0;

// FFT1D on rows
for(int i = 0 ; i < nrRowTargetVector ; i++)
{
    std::vector<complex> tempVectorFFT;
    for (int j = 0; j < nrColTargetVector; j++)
        tempVectorFFT.push_back(complexVictor[i * nrColTargetVector + j]);
    std::vector<complex> tempFFTtransformROW = newFFT->transform(tempVectorFFT);
    copy(tempFFTtransformROW.begin(), tempFFTtransformROW.end(), back_inserter(fft1DTargetVectorRows));
}

//FFT1D on columns
fft2Cols = (fft1DTargetVectorRows.size()/nrRowTargetVector);
fft2DTargetVector.reserve(0*0);

for(int i = 0; i <fft2Cols ; i++)
{
    std::vector<complex> tempVectorFFT;
    for (int j = 0; j < nrRowTargetVector; j++)
        tempVectorFFT.push_back(fft1DTargetVectorRows[i + fft2Cols *j]);
    std::vector<complex> tempFFTtransformCOLUMN = newFFT->transform(tempVectorFFT);
    if(!flag)
    {
        //to insert values at certain indexes we need to resize the result vector
        fft2Rows = tempFFTtransformCOLUMN.size();
        fft2DTargetVector.reserve(fft2Rows*fft2Cols);
        flag ++;
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < tempFFTtransformCOLUMN.size(); k++)
        fft2DTargetVector[i + tempFFTtransformCOLUMN.size() * k] = tempFFTtransformCOLUMN[k];
}
```

My FFT1D algorithm is doing padding until the next position power of 2. So for each row i am adding 0-s until position 32 and then on each column the same.

I have a suspicion that the 0-padding to each line and then column is not really correct since it adds 0-s in between the 1D vector's position that holds my data .

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code. As is I don’t see how we could help you?

Comment: I suggest fully implementing the 1D case first.

Comment: And probably do it interactively in Python with an IDE like Spyder to save tons of time, then can copy to C++.