# 2D FFT Cross-Correlation in Python

Tags: fft, image-processing, python, dft, cross-correlation

How to replicate `scipy.signal.correlate2d(x, h)` with arbitrarily sized `x` and `h`? `ifft2(fft2(x) * conj(fft2(h)))` gives bad results. I've read related Q&As but they either do circular cross-correlation, or do convolution which doesn't easily translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replicated `scipy.signal.correlate2d` for all `mode` - `'full'`, `'same'`, `'valid'`.
Scipy's cross-correlation, interestingly, agrees with my philosophy of being [defined "backwards"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/82446/50076). This means we can't simply run `convolve` logic with a conjugated + flipped kernel, except for `'full'` output mode (with correct padding).

The filter/template $h$ sweeps the input $x$, in a non-commutative manner, including in output shape. The idea is, we seek similarities of template with input at every point **of input**:

- `'same'`: unpadding is such that `out.shape == x.shape`, and the filter overlaps the input by at least half its size.
- `'valid'`: here the idea mimics `convolve`, except for when $h$ is larger than $x$. Then, `scipy` does something I can't understand, and it differs from its 1D correlate: it swaps the inputs to convolve faster, but then instead of flipping the output and conjugating, it only flips. I've not investigated, just reproduced it.

I've only implemented zero-padding. Non-zero padding is tricky and more complicated if it is to remain performant.

#### Extra speedups

1. `next_fast_len`: FFTs are done with fast FFT lengths instead of naive padding
2. `workers`: multiprocessing FFTs, scipy's feature
3. Don't explicitly pad, instead take bigger FFTs
4. `inplace`: operate in-place where possible instead of allocating new arrays
5. `reusables`: if $x$ has the same shape and $h$ doesn't change, we effectively cache what computation's in common
6. `real`: if $x$ and $h$ are real-valued, skip `conj`

Instead of conjugating `fft`, I conjugate then flip $h$, which is faster for `real` but otherwise slower. Conjugating `fft` is also tricker to implement efficiently.

#### Code + testing

Available at [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/StackExchangeAnswers/tree/main/SignalProcessing/Q87781%20-%20cross-correlation%2C%20FFT%20-%202D%20Cross-Correlation%20using%20FFT%20in%20Python).

#### Just the function

***Not up to date***, I'll only be updating the Github code.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
from scipy.fft import next_fast_len, fft2, ifft2

def cross_correlate_2d(x, h, mode='same', real=True, get_reusables=False):
    """2D cross-correlation, replicating `scipy.signal.correlate2d`.

    `reusables` are passed in as `h`.
    Set `get_reusables=True` to return `out, reusables`.
    """
    # check if `h` is reusables
    if not isinstance(h, tuple):
        # fetch shapes, check inputs
        xs, hs = x.shape, h.shape
        h_not_smaller = all(hs[i] >= xs[i] for i in (0, 1))
        x_not_smaller = all(xs[i] >= hs[i] for i in (1, 0))
        if mode == 'valid' and not (h_not_smaller or x_not_smaller):
            raise ValueError(
                "For `mode='valid'`, every axis in `x` must be at least "
                "as long as in `h`, or vice versa. Got x:{}, h:{}".format(
                                 str(xs), str(hs)))

        # swap if needed
        swap = bool(mode == 'valid' and not x_not_smaller)
        if swap:
            xadj, hadj = h, x
        else:
            xadj, hadj = x, h
        xs, hs = xadj.shape, hadj.shape

        # compute pad quantities
        full_len_h = xs[0] + hs[0] - 1
        full_len_w = xs[1] + hs[1] - 1
        padded_len_h = next_fast_len(full_len_h)
        padded_len_w = next_fast_len(full_len_w)
        padded_shape = (padded_len_h, padded_len_w)

        # compute unpad indices
        if mode == 'full':
            offset_h, offset_w = 0, 0
            len_h, len_w = full_len_h, full_len_w
        elif mode == 'same':
            len_h, len_w = xs
            offset_h, offset_w = [g//2 for g in hs]
        elif mode == 'valid':
            ax_pairs = ((xs[0], hs[0]), (xs[1], hs[1]))
            len_h, len_w = [max(g) - min(g) + 1 for g in ax_pairs]
            offset_h, offset_w = [min(g) - 1 for g in ax_pairs]
        unpad_h = slice(offset_h, offset_h + len_h)
        unpad_w = slice(offset_w, offset_w + len_w)

        # handle filter / template
        if real:
            hadj = hadj[::-1, ::-1]
        else:
            hadj = np.conj(hadj)[::-1, ::-1]
        hf = fft2(hadj, padded_shape)
    else:
        reusables = h
        (hf, swap, padded_shape, unpad_h, unpad_w) = reusables
        if swap:
            xadj, hadj = h, x
        else:
            xadj, hadj = x, h

    # FFT convolution
    out = ifft2(fft2(xadj, padded_shape) * hf)
    if real:
        out = out.real

    # unpad, unswap
    out = out[unpad_h, unpad_w]
    if swap:
        out = out[::-1, ::-1]

    # pack reusables
    if get_reusables:
        reusables = (hf, swap, padded_shape, unpad_h, unpad_w)

    # return
    return ((out, reusables) if get_reusables else
            out)
```